# Inverse (Column) Row-Major Order Transformation

Tags: math

Can anyone provide/refer to the inverse of the 'indices -> offset'* transformation for Multi-Dimensional Row-Major Order. Also, (pseudo)code would be appreciated.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

To give an example, an simplification of the particular problem which prompted my question:
I have a 3 dimensional data hierarchy, expressed in the space spanned by (a,b,c) where a, b, and c are integers larger or equal zero and less then N_a, N_b, and N_c. I want to express the data an one dimensional array. The "offset," In Row-Major Order, is then given as follows:

```
 int offset(a, b, c){
      return a*N_b*N_c + b*N_c + c;
}
```

What is then the reverse transformation, i.e.:

```
int a(int offset);
int b(int offset);
int c(int offset);
```

Furthermore, how to i generalise this to N'th dimension indexation? The problem which prompted this question is of 5'th dimension.

In case it matters, I am writing in c/c++.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify your question a little bit? I think I might be able to help, but I don't quite know what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the index is calculated as

```
offset = row + column*NUMROWS
```

then the inverse would be

```
row = offset % NUMROWS
column = offset / NUMROWS
```

where `%` is modulus, and `/` is integer division.

This assumes the first element is at offset 0, row 0 and column 0. If they start at 1, you would have to add or subtract 1 at appropriate places.

---

For higher dimensions, you will have to repeat this for every measure.

```
offset = x + WIDTH*(y + HEIGHT*(z + DEPTH*time));
```

and the inverse

```
x = offset % WIDTH
offset = offset / WIDTH

y = offset % HEIGHT
offset = offset / HEIGHT

z = offset % DEPTH
offset = offset / DEPTH

time = offset
```

You could also extract a specific coordinate:

```
z = (offset / (WIDTH * HEIGHT)) % DEPTH
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am actually asking because i have a 5-dimensional indexed case. I am sorry for not making this clear. I will do so in the OP shortly.

Comment: Here: https://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/7.Arrays/row_major.html the formula is a bit different